# Update form with new input fileds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a wizard plug-in. In that wizard I have a form in which I dynamically create new `<input>` fields. The problem is that, when I execute the submit in the POST I can't find the new fileds.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have some code in your page? If, yes, post the relevant part here...

Comment: If you don't show us any code, we can't really help

Comment: Not all kind of problem requires code

Comment: Are you sure that you add the `name` attribute to your elements?

Comment: Yes @sdespont I'm sure! As said, I think that the bind with the submit event is already done, so when I change the form, I need to rebind the event

Comment: Add your code here. Actually all problems need a part/whole code. Can you repair my car if i have no car? The problem might be on adding names for inputs. Do they have all of them different names or an array name (name="myinput[]");

Comment: If I ask you where is the spare wheel you can help me also without see my car. The code is not mine, is a plug-in http://themeforest.net/item/mws-admin-full-featured-admin-template/1460451 The only problem I have is that when I add new fields in the form, the only fileds send in post are the previous existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/125/

```
<form id="mydiv">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<button id="btn">Add</button>

i=0;
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#submit').before("<input name='test"+i+"' value='test' />");
    i++;
});

$('form').submit(function(){
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is, when you dynamically generate `input`-fields, you have to give them a `name`. When the form is posted, only those with names get to the server.

```
<form action="wherever" method="post">
    // Stuff
    <input name="myshinynewfield"/>
    // More Stuff
</form>
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) for more info on how the data is encoded.

Comment: I think that maybe the bind with the submit event is already done, so when I change the form, I need to rebind the event

Comment: What are you talking about?